# How to find a role by name and add a user to it (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to create a bot that is more universal and can be added to more than one server. I've managed to reformat commands like announce or join messages etc. by using `.find("name", "announcements")`.

My problem is that the same does not work for roles.

I've tried what little I could find on the internet, such as `member.guild.roles.find("name", "Member")` or `member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member")` but none of these work. A variety of different ways return different errors, but they usually say something along the lines of it not being an integer (I think) or snowflake.

This is the function that I am currently wrestling with:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    var joinResponse = ("Hello **" + member.displayName + "**, welcome to **" + member.guild.name + "**!")
    let role = member.guild.roles.find("name", "Member");
    member.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
    member.guild.channels.find('name', 'general').send(joinResponse);
```

In short summary, what I'm looking for is the ability to get a role by name and add a user to it.

(I'm nearly certain it's possible, since popular bots like Dyno are capable of using commands to add roles to users.)

Comment: Your code works just fine maybe the role "Member" doesn't exists on your server.

Comment: @cursed im so mad at myself you don't even understand

Comment: yeah so that was the problem, my code was just find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    const joinResponse = `Hello **${member.user.username}**, welcome to: **${member.guild.name}**!`
    let role = member.guild.roles.get('Member');
    if(!role) return console.log("Role doesen't exist.");
    member.addRole(role);
    const ch = member.guild.channels.get('general');
    if(!ch) return console.log("Channel doesen't exist.");
    ch.send(joinResponse);
});//You didn't have closing brackets (Could've been a problem)
```

First of all your string **joinResponse** was a function and you completely messed up merging it, I recommend using [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I used [get](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) function since it's a lot easier to use and cleaner, you only pass ID or name as a [string](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp).

To check **if channel exists** I used [if statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) and [exclamation mark](https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-bang-bang-i-shot-you-down-use-of-double-bangs-in-javascript-7c9d94446054%20%7C) which means doesen't exist/false.

If I helped you please mark this as answer, thanks <3. If you need anything add comment to answer or message me on Discord (You can find my discriminator on my [stack overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12042113/petar190)).

For further explanation click on Blue words.

Comment: Since this question shows up at the top of google, I would like to point out that this no longer works. You need to search the cached roles now. So you would do this instead: `message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'My Role Name')`.