# DiscordAPIERROR: Unknown Role (discord.js v12)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**Concept**: Checking if a user has a role in one guild & if the user has that role it will give the user a role in another guild.

The bot is above the role and has permissions to add roles.

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content === "$sync") {
    // ROLEID is the role being checked
    if(!message.member.roles.cache.has(`ROLEID`)){
      message.reply(`You do not have the role`) 
  } else {
    const otherguild = message.client.guilds.cache.get('GUILDID');

  //Define role
  const role = otherguild.roles.cache.get('ROLE-ID');

  //add role to user in other guild
  message.member.roles.add(role);
    console.log(`${role} has been added to ${message.author.username}.`);
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Discord IDs are all unique generated based on timestamp and a few other things. The role from guild 1 cannot be present in guild 2 with the same ID. If you want to search guild 2's roles for one with the same *name* have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864010/how-to-find-a-role-by-name-and-add-a-user-to-it-discord-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add it to the member in the original guild while the role belongs to the other guild. You need to get the member from the other guild and add the role there

```js
const otherguild = message.client.guilds.cache.get('GUILDID')
const role = otherguild.roles.cache.get('ROLE-ID')
const othermember = await otherguild.members.fetch(message.author.id)
othermember.roles.add(role)
```